# Nutch bin/crawl script is failing - Manual steps work fine

Tags: apache, shell, solr, nutch

I'm trying to run the script provided in Nutch 1.6 "bin/crawl" which does all of the manual steps below required to go off and spider a site.

When I run these steps manually everything works fine and my page is indexed as expected (albeit only one page but will look into this)

created text file containing a URL @ seeds/urls.txt

```
bin/nutch inject crawl_test/crawldb seeds/

bin/nutch generate crawl_test/crawldb crawl_test/segments

export SEGMENT=crawl_test/segments/`ls -tr crawl_test/segments|tail -1`

bin/nutch fetch $SEGMENT -noParsing

bin/nutch parse $SEGMENT

bin/nutch updatedb crawl_test/crawldb $SEGMENT -filter -normalize

bin/nutch invertlinks crawl_test/linkdb -dir crawl_test/segments

bin/nutch solrindex http://dev:8080/solr/ crawl_test/crawldb -linkdb crawl_test/linkdb crawl_test/segments/*
```

The bin/crawl script gives this error...

> ```
> Indexing 20130412115759 on SOLR index -> someurl:8080/solr/
> SolrIndexer: starting at 2013-04-12 11:58:47
> SolrIndexer: deleting gone documents: false
> SolrIndexer: URL filtering: false
> SolrIndexer: URL normalizing: false
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/opt/nutch/20130412115759/crawl_fetch
> Input path does not exist: file:/opt/nutch/20130412115759/crawl_parse
> Input path does not exist: file:/opt/nutch/20130412115759/parse_data
> Input path does not exist: file:/opt/nutch/20130412115759/parse_text
> ```

Any idea why this script isn't working? I think it must be an error in the script itself rather then my config as the path it is looking for doesn't exist and not sure why it would even be looking there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a bug with the [bin/crawl](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1500) script

```
-  $bin/nutch solrindex $SOLRURL $CRAWL_PATH/crawldb -linkdb $CRAWL_PATH/linkdb $SEGMENT
+  $bin/nutch solrindex $SOLRURL $CRAWL_PATH/crawldb -linkdb $CRAWL_PATH/linkdb $CRAWL_PATH/segments/$SEGMENT
```